# Why are common inequalities like C-S, the Means Inequalities, Hölder's inequality, etc, all homogeneous?

Tags: inequality, soft-question

Why are decently tightly bounded, common/well-known inequalities like Cauchy-Sschwarz, The Rearrangement inequality, Chebychev's inequality, the Means Inequalities, Hölder's inequality, etc, **all homogeneous**, that is:

$$ f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \leq g(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \implies f(\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2, \ldots, \lambda x_n) \leq g( \lambda x_1, \lambda x_2, \ldots, \lambda x_n)\ ? $$

I wonder if there is any intuition for why this is the case.

I'm not sure if Bernoulli's inequality is homogeneous, but Bernoulli's inequality is a bit different in nature to the previously-mentioned ones, which is to do with squaring, cubing, square roots, cube roots, etc etc.

Maybe my question is just me showing off an *interesting observation*, that is, that all of these common inequalities are homogeneous. And asking "why is this the case?" is not clear what I am asking. Would people agree with this analysis of my own question, or is there actually something to my question?

Comment: Some of these can be proved with the rearrangement inequality or Jensen's inequality. So they're related

Comment: At least Cauchy-Schwarz, AM-GM, Holder's inequality, have convexity at their heart. I think it is somehow morally related.

Comment: Bernoulli's inequality, for positive values, definitely has the convexity property too.

Comment: Polynomial inequalities are often written in symmetric homogeneous forms.  Not necessary though.  For e.g. the 2 variable AM-GM $x^2+y^2\geqslant 2xy$ is equivalent to $a^2+1\geqslant 2a$, replacing $a=x/y$ in the latter gives you back the nice symmetric homogeneous form on clearing denominators.  Taking other similar inequalities and using symmetry to reduce a variable will give you equivalent non-homogenous form.  OTOH, Bernoulli's inequality deals with convex exponential curves bounded by its tangent lines, so it effectively smashes the exponent down to linear form.

Comment: My two cents is that this just some form of our bias - we simply do not have any set of powerful and fundamental tools to attack non-homogenous inequalities. I don't  honestly think we ever will though. 

Any continuous inequality can be attacked via standard calculus tools by turning it into an optimization problem. But for hard problems, this essentially turns into solving set of non-linear equations for local extrema, which is usually intractable symbolically.

Comment: "Polynomial inequalities are often written in symmetric homogeneous forms." Ok, so can every tight polynomial inequality be written in symmetric homogeneous form?

Comment: I think my question is really about the *degree* of both sides. And so the answer is that, if the degree of both sides is different, then the side with greater degree will dominate.